# Apt-get update weak digest algorithm

Tags: gnome, 64-bit, laptop, lenovo, amd-processor

I tried everything i could find...

This is error when i use `apt-get update`

```
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-fatal fault at the repository end.  What you're seeing is a report that the repository's signature is less secure than it probably ought to be, but this won't prevent updates from downloading and installing.  The warning is provided so you can (in the case of a private repository, I presume) let the repo admins know they need to update their encryption and signatures.

I saw that warning every update for weeks concerning Firefox -- it seems to be corrected there now, but it appears you're seeing it on one or more of Canonical's repos.  My presumption is that they'll fix it soon, though with Precise Pangolin nearing end of life, that may be a reduced priority.